# Selecting individual nav elements in CSS/CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do i go about selecting nav elements in CSS3?

I want to be able to make a nav element - when hovered - change to a color i want.

Such as

```
<nav>
    <a href="#mainpage">first</a>  // i want to make this word, when hovered, into #555
    <a href="#secondpage">second</a>  // i want to make this word, when hovered, into #444
    <a href="#thirdpage">third</a>  //i want to make this word, when hovered, into #643312
    <a href="#fourthpage">fourth</a>  //i want to make this word, when hovered, into #444
    <a href="#fifthpage">fifth</a>  // i want to make this word, when hovered, into #666
</nav>
```

How do i actually go about doing that?

I am reading about the CSS3 selectors but i don't see any solutions (well at least not yet), so i'd thought i'll get a faster answer here on Stack Overflow. I'll continue searching to see if i yield any results.

Comment: nav:nth-child(1):hover. i don't think its working. :P

Comment: wait, i left out a, that was crucial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for `when hovered`:  (not sure your question isn't very descriptive)

```
nav a:nth-child(1):hover
{
    color: #555
}
nav a:nth-child(2):hover
{
    color: #444
}
nav a:nth-child(3):hover
{
    color: #643312
}
nav a:nth-child(4):hover
{
    color: #444
}
nav a:nth-child(5):hover
{
    color: #666
}
```

[JsFiddle.net Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PGqUK/)​

**UPDATE**

If you're wondering how every **N** works:

```
<style>
nav a:nth-child(3n+0):hover {
  background-color: #f00;
}
nav a:nth-child(3n+1):hover {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
nav a:nth-child(3n+2):hover {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
<style>

<nav>
 <a href="#mainpage">first</a> 
 <a href="#secondpage">second</a> 
 <a href="#thirdpage">third</a>  
 <a href="#fourthpage">fourth</a> 
 <a href="#fifthpage">fifth</a>  
 <a href="#sixthpage">sixth</a>  
</nav> ​
```

[JsFiddle.net Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RmytA/)

Elements (0, 3, 6, 9 etc) will be Green (#f00).

Elements (1, 4, 7, 10 etc) will be Blue (#0f0).

Elements (2, 5, 8, 11 etc) will be Red (#00f).

Comment: awesome. understanding this will definitely help in future. thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

check this one:

[click here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

do you want this ?

```
nav a:nth-child(2),
nav a:nth-child(4),
nav a:nth-child(6){

....something

}








nav a:nth-child(2)
{
background:#ff0000;
}
```

Comment: hmm, was reading about that, so a value of 2 sets the second nav link to a certain colour you like, and so on and so forth?

Comment: yeah i read about that, but it got me confused because it was saying it would select every "nth" child from the element, meaning that i thought it would select the nav elements 2, 4, 6, 8... if i put nav:nth-child(2). turns out you actually need nav:nth-child(n+2) or something to make that work. or nav:nth-child(even).

Comment: no, i'm looking for what Erik provided, thanks anyway! i've implemented the code, works fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSS 2.1 solution to this :)

If you want to style your first link you may use `nav a:first-child` selector, for the second one and on you can use the sibling selectors like so:

```
nav a:first-child + a{
    color: red; //coloring the second link
}
nav a:first-child + a + a{
    color: green; //coloring the third link
}
nav a:first-child + a + a + a{
    color: black; //coloring the fourth link
}
nav a:first-child + a + a + a + a{
    color: yellow; //coloring the fifth link
}
```

Such a solution would work from IE7 up.

Comment: not really supporting browsers using anything below CSS3 for this project, but good answer for those looking for 2.1 support